# Exercise: interpretation of terms in black-scholes

Tags: black-scholes, risk-neutral-measure

I have following exercise:

[image]

This is what I did:

\begin{align}
 C(K)&= e^{-r\tau} \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[((S_T - K)^+] \\
&= e^{-r\tau}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[((S_T - K)\mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}] \\
&=e^{-r\tau}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[S_T \mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}]-Ke^{-r\tau}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}]
\end{align}

by$ \mathbb{1}$ I mean indicator function. Now I understand that
$$ \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}] = \mathbb{Q}(S_T>K) $$

however I don't know how to deal with
$$\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[S_T \mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}]$$

is this the right way how to solve this exercise?

Comment: This is simply an integration for S(T) > K. The density function is log-normal. You'll need to substitute the density function into the equation and do the integration. It's not very hard.

Comment: Indeed. You can also do it the "hard way" through a change of numéraire (or Bayes' rule for conditional expectations). The latter option requires a good command of stochastic calculus though, while the approach proposed by @Student T only requires a good command of standard calculus. Also, this question is tackled in any good textbook (see the steps here: http://www.valonews.com/?p=612, although text is in french) and is a little bit basic for this forum.

Comment: For such question, there are a lot of discussions on this site based on either a brute force approach, or a numeraire change approach. By the way, should $S_t\pmb{1}_{S_T>K}$ be $S_T\pmb{1}_{S_T>K}$?

Comment: For example, see [this](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/25711/understanding-the-solution-of-this-integral/25713#25713) and [this](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/why-nd-1-and-nd-2-are-different-in-black-scholes/19085#19085). You can search the tag *black-scholes*.

Comment: For the last term I think the question wants you to switch to the stock numeraire and then it equals S(t) times the expectation of the indicator under the stock measure.  (Apologies I can't write symbols on my phone )